# Pandas column split ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe structured like:

| Location_Identifier | Location_Name | Location_Type | Observed_Property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5728 | place 1 | Groundwater | 39398 - ETHION IN WHOLE WATER SAMPLE (UG/L) |
| 535 | place 2 | Groundwater | 946 - SULFATE, DISSOLVED (MG/L AS SO4) |
| 1003 | place 3 | Groundwater | 1145 - SELENIUM, DISSOLVED (UG/L AS SE) |
| 12151 | place 4 | Surface Water | 94 - SPECIFIC CONDUCTANCE, FIELD (UMHOS/CM @ 25C) |
| 1571 | place 5 | Groundwater | 82078 - TURBIDITY, FIELD NEPHELOMETRIC TURBIDITY UNITS (NTU) |
| 8094 | place 6 | Spring | 90068 - SAMPLE DEPTH FROM SURFACE (METERS) |
| 2778 | place 7 | Groundwater | 1044 - IRON, SUSPENDED (UG/L AS FE) |

When I attempt to split the "Observed Property" field, I receive the following error:

```
df[["pcode","pname"]] = df["Observed_Property"].str.split('-',expand=True)
```

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Is that the full dataset? Are there columns where there are more than one dashed line? Or where there is nothing before and after the dashed line? The error suggests that the split is not always returning 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and I am fairly certain you have some values in "Observed_Property" That have more than one '-' so when you split the values, you get more than 2 columns.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


dfstr = """Location_Identifier  Location_Name   Location_Type   Observed_Property
5728    place 1 Groundwater 39398 - ETHION IN WHOLE WATER SAMPLE (UG/L)
535 place 2 Groundwater 946 - SULFATE, DISSOLVED (MG/L AS SO4)
1003    place 3 Groundwater 1145 - SELENIUM, DISSOLVED (UG/L AS SE)
12151   place 4 Surface Water   94 - SPECIFIC CONDUCTANCE, FIELD (UMHOS/CM @ 25C)
1571    place 5 Groundwater 82078 - TURBIDITY, FIELD NEPHELOMETRIC TURBIDITY UNITS (NTU)
8094    place 6 Spring  90068 - SAMPLE DEPTH FROM SURFACE (METERS)
2778    place 7 Groundwater 1044 - IRON, SUSPENDED (UG/L AS FE)"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfstr), sep='\t')

df[["pcode","pname"]] = df["Observed_Property"].str.split('-',expand=True)
```

If I just use your example df and run your split code, it works as expected. But, I can break it by adding a value to 'Oberserved_Property' that has two '-'.

```
df.loc[6] = [1234, 'place 8', 'Groundwater', '12345 - Name-of-place']
```

|  | Location_Identifier | Location_Name | Location_Type | Observed_Property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5728 | place 1 | Groundwater | 39398 - ETHION IN WHOLE WATER SAMPLE (UG/L) |
| 1 | 535 | place 2 | Groundwater | 946 - SULFATE, DISSOLVED (MG/L AS SO4) |
| 2 | 1003 | place 3 | Groundwater | 1145 - SELENIUM, DISSOLVED (UG/L AS SE) |
| 3 | 12151 | place 4 | Surface Water | 94 - SPECIFIC CONDUCTANCE, FIELD (UMHOS/CM @ 25C) |
| 4 | 1571 | place 5 | Groundwater | 82078 - TURBIDITY, FIELD NEPHELOMETRIC TURBIDI... |
| 5 | 8094 | place 6 | Spring | 90068 - SAMPLE DEPTH FROM SURFACE (METERS) |
| 6 | 1234 | place 8 | Groundwater | 12345 - Name-of-place |

Now if I run the same code I get same error as you.

```
df[["pcode","pname"]] = df["Observed_Property"].str.split('-',expand=True)
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

One way you can get around this is by passing in a more stringent split argument.

```
df[["pcode","pname"]] = df["Observed_Property"].str.split('[0-9] -',expand=True)
```

This tells pandas to split on a digit ([0-9]) followed by a space and a '-'. This will then prevent it from splitting on other '-' that is not preceded by a digit. Based on what the rest of your data looks like you can modify the regex and get the right split.